# Load website when progress finishs

Tags: jquery, css

I have created a div, with the name of my website. When you enter in the website, you see the **name getting filled** (like a **progress bar**). It's supposed that when the name is **COMPLETELY** filled, the div **dissapears**; but it dissapears when it's not totally filled. More or less in the **50%**...

**Can you please help me?**

**You can check it out in the next link: ** [tapeHD](http://tapehd.hostei.com)

**Here's the code...**

**JQUERY code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /* Loading */
    $(window).load(function () { $('body').addClass('loading'); });

    setTimeout(function() {
        if($('body').hasClass('loading')) {
            $('#loading').fadeOut();
            $('body').removeClass('loading');
            $('body').addClass('loaded');
        }
    }, 2000);

    if($.cookie('showOnlyOnce')){
        $('#loading').hide();
    } else {
        $.cookie('showOnlyOnce', 'showOnlyOnce', { expires: 1 });
        $('#loading').show();
    }
    /* END Loading */
});
```

**CSS3 code**

```
body.loading #loading .title2 span,
body.loading #loading h1 .progress_bar_container .progress_bar {
    width: 100%;
}

body.loaded #loading .title2 span,
body.loaded #loading h1 .progress_bar_container .progress_bar {
    width: 100%;
}

#loading {
    background-color: #252328;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

#loading .container {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    width: 29rem;
}

#loading h1 {
    bottom: 0;
    font-family: CaviarDreams_Bold;
    font-size: 8.2rem;
    height: 1.4em;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
}

#loading h1 span {
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    line-height: normal;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

#loading h1 .progress_bar_container {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);    
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    height: 7%;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 36%;
}

#loading h1 .progress_bar_container .progress_bar {
    background-color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 0%;

    -webkit-transition: width 2s linear;
       -moz-transition: width 2s linear;
        -ms-transition: width 2s linear;
         -o-transition: width 2s linear;
            transition: width 2s linear;
}

#loading .title1 {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}

#loading .title2 { color: #FFF; }

#loading .title2 span {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 0%;

    -webkit-transition: width 2s linear;
       -moz-transition: width 2s linear;
        -ms-transition: width 2s linear;
         -o-transition: width 2s linear;
            transition: width 2s linear;
}
```

The div has set a cookie. It's only shown once per day. Clean cookies to display it everytime you enter in the website...

---

I have tried this with animate function

```
var progress = false;

$(window).load(function () { $('body').addClass('loading'); });

if($('body').hasClass('loading')) { progress = true; }

if(progress == true) {
    $("body.loading #loading .tapeHDProgress").animate({ width: "100%" }, 2000, function() {
        $('#loading').fadeOut();
        $('body').removeClass('loading');
        $('body').addClass('loaded');
    });
}
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Hmm my first guess is that your current approach will always be unreliable in this respect. Here's what I understand you're doing:

- CSS is configured such that the loading bar takes 2 seconds to fill up.
- You've set a Javascript timer to fade out the loading div after 2 seconds.
- These two processes are completely unrelated to each other; you're counting on the browser's timing precision for them to be synchronized.

As with any advanced CSS trickery, different browsers will handle this differently so you can't expect a consistent experience. For example, in Chrome the effect appears to work fine (the loading screen shows up for 2 seconds, then fades out on cue); in Firefox and Safari the screen doesn't fade out at all (you might want to check on that; I'm on OSX Yosemite.)

If you really need the 2 processes to be synchronized, I'd use something like Jquery's `.animate()` which allows you to specify an animation and duration, but also lets you specify a piece of JS code that should be executed *right when the animation completes*. That way you're not relying on 2 separate processes to be synchronized; the completion of the loading bar actually *triggers* the fadeout.

Comment: I took a look at your solution and it looks like you're using `if` statements which will **only execute once**. You want to set up a piece of Javascript code that will execute *immediately after* the animation is complete; see this page on other users' discussion about a similar situation. https://forum.jquery.com/topic/call-function-after-animation

Comment: The problem is not the function after the animation, the problem is that the animation, in that way, doesn't even work...

Comment: So...? Any idea about that?